# Custom View animations are smooth on emulators but choppy on real devices

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, android-custom-view

I've been working on custom view for an `android app`,
I added animations and found that they were smooth on `emulators` but rough on the real phone;

[image: Emulator Animation]

[image: Device Animation]

it isn't as clear in the gifs but the emulator is much smoother. The device used was a Galaxy Note 5 if that helps.

```
 public void animateLayout(){
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(25,displayHeight -initHeight);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getWidth(), initHeight + (int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
            setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            gameViewVisible = true;
            animateArc();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    if(gameViewVisible == false) {
        valueAnimator.start();
    }


}

public void animateArc(){
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,achievmentProgress);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(achievmentProgress*(int)4.7);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            achievmentDegrees = (int)animation.getAnimatedValue();
            invalidate();


        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();
}
```

These are the animations I use, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone is trying to figure this out, here's what I did to solve the issue. I moved all bitmap allocations to the onSizeChanged method. Now every time I call invalidate in these animations it doesn't have to redraw the large Bitmaps and is smoother all around.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting animation duration. Try to increase animation duration. Because rendering on real device is faster than emulator.